# When should I use html's <form> and when spring's <form:form> in Spring MVC web app?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, forms

I am wondering is it good practice to write all forms in spring tags or can I mix spring form tags with html form tags?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Spring forms when you need functionality provided by them:

- binding to objects
- configurable field formatting
- redisplay of values on errors
- binding of error messages

For simple forms (such as a simple search box on each page) you usually don't need these features - therefore you can use simple HTML forms for them.

Comment: Is there any advantages of binding object to form with spring form and manually setting path to object in name part of form element?  Ex: <form:input path="parent.name" /> and <input name="parent.name" /> on server side. If later doesn't bind object than what is object binding and what it's advantages?

Comment: form:form will also add CSRT token automatically. If you don't use it and having CSRF tokens, dont forget to add <input type="hidden"
 name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
 value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Comment: Can you describe precisely what the differences are

Answer (score 3):

Springs `form:form` tag is supposed to be used with whenever you have a `formbacking` object you wish to bind to the form (a `model` object delivered to your view).

There are no additional benefits of using the tag in a regular form with no backing object.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in addition to binding data with Model Attribute, Spring Form also helps us by auto-create CSRF token and inserting it into our form (Spring Security).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).