# Proper use of Spring tag library in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

If I don't use `<% @ taglibprefix = "sf" uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`
the application works the same. The User user object is filled with the fields of the form. Is it correct to use this approach?

Is the use of `<sf:form method="POST"modelAttribute="user">` more correct?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Inserisci nuovo utente</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Dati utente</h2>
<form action="/SpringMVCFormHibernate/add" method="post">
    <label>Cognome</label><br/><input type="text" name="cognome"/><br/>
    <label>Nome</label><br/><input type="text" name="nome"/><br/>
    <label>Eta</label><br/><input type="text" name="eta"/><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<p><a href="/SpringMVCFormHibernate/show">Visualizza utenti</a></p>
<sf:label path=""></sf:label>
</body>
</html>

@Controller
public class UtenteController {

@Autowired
UtenteDAO utenteDAO;

@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUtente(@ModelAttribute Utente user){
    utenteDAO.inserisciUtente(user);
    return "index";
}//addUtente
}//UtenteController
```

Comment: _The User user object is filled with the fields of the form. Is it correct to use this approach_ How do you do without form tags . Are you using jstl ?

Comment: A side note: please consider using `UTF-8` instead `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: yes i'm using jstl but the form dosn't specify the model attribute..the spring form instead yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major use of `spring:form` tag is `formbacking` object . If you wish to bind the model attribute object with the view fields , you can go for it .

For simple form objects you can use html forms instead . Also you can make use of `spring:form` tags error attributes as well.

for **ex**,

`path` attribute binds the model field name . so changes made to them are can be easily updated in the server side with your model attribute.

simply they provide dyanamic binding of objects easily . spring does those instead of manual works

A [nice example](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-handling/) to understand form handling and model attribute usage.

Comment: the html form dosn't specify the model attribute..but The User user object is filled with the fields of the form..Why?

Comment: because the model attributes are request . so it is made available

Comment: But ,for example, if i have two jsp with two form  how do they figure out which object are binding?If html form dosn't specify model attribute the parameters of the first form can mixing with the wrong item

Comment: modelAttribute decides it :)

Comment: So there is no difference between html form and spring form?Both realize the binding?

Comment: form backing object is the major difference . for others see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078858/when-should-i-use-htmls-form-and-when-springs-formform-in-spring-mvc-web

Comment: in this case there is "backing object", or not? I don't use request.getProperty() in controller but i hava all in the item user